# Ubuntu 20.04 Mono CSC Compile Not Working

Tags: 20.04, compiling, mono

I receive an error when compiling "hello.cs":

```
using System;

public class HelloWorld
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

using CSC, installed using chicken-bin:

```
$ csc hello.cs

Syntax error: illegal atomic form: ()
inside expression `(scheme#string ...)'


    Expansion history:

    <syntax>      (##core#begin (public static void Main (string () args) (Console.WriteLine ("Hello World!"))))
    <syntax>      (public static void Main (string () args) (Console.WriteLine ("Hello World!")))
    <syntax>      (string () args)  <--

Error: shell command terminated with non-zero exit status 17920: '/usr/bin/chicken' 'hello.cs' -output-file 'hello.c'
```

I have gone through installation instructions from both Linuxize and AskUbuntu. A search deals mostly with monodevelop, while I installed mono-complete. I also ran mono-runtime, but everything it installs was already installed and current. The mono --V command gives an atypical result, in that LLVM is not enabled:

```
Mono JIT compiler version 6.8.0.105 (Debian 6.8.0.105+dfsg-2 Wed Feb 26 23:23:50 UTC 2020)
Copyright (C) 2002-2014 Novell, Inc, Xamarin Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
    TLS:           __thread
    SIGSEGV:       altstack
    Notifications: epoll
    Architecture:  amd64
    Disabled:      none
    Misc:          softdebug 
    Interpreter:   yes
    LLVM:          supported, not enabled.
    Suspend:       hybrid
    GC:            sgen (concurrent by default)
```

an attempt to enable LLVM using mono --llvm gives:

```
Mono Warning: --llvm not enabled in this runtime.
```

It then lists the usage instructions for mono.

How might I be able to correct this? If you need any further information, please ask.

Comment: This is usually solved by adding `--enable-llvm` to `autogen.sh/configure` when compiling.

Comment: This was installed from a compiled package per directions at Linuxize. No requirement was stated for compiling or recompiling, so I would think it should work per the directions. The same for Ask Ubuntu. Especially when the directions are specifically written for 20.04.

Answer (score 0):

I think the command is `mono-csc hello.cs`. Those websites seem to be wrong for Ubuntu. Suppose this was a way to resolve a naming conflict with chicken-bin package.